# Detect overlaping if enumerating nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like to know how should I detect overlapping nodes while enumerating them? Or how should I make that every random generated position in **Y axis** is at least some points higher or lower.

This is what I do:

1 - Generate random number between -400 and 400

2 - Add those into array

3 - Enumerate and add nodes to scene with generated positions like this:

```
var leftPositions = [CGPoint]()

            for _ in 0..<randRange(lower: 1, upper: 5){
                leftPositions.append(CGPoint(x: -295, y: Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: leftSparkMinimumY, secondNumber: leftSparkMaximumY)))

            }

            leftPositions.enumerated().forEach { (index, point) in

                let leftSparkNode = SKNode()
                leftSparkNode.position = point
                leftSparkNode.name = "LeftSparks"

                let leftSparkTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "LeftSpark")
                LeftSpark = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftSparkTexture)

                LeftSpark.name = "LeftSparks"
                LeftSpark.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: leftSparkTexture, size: LeftSpark.size)
                LeftSpark.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.LeftSpark
                LeftSpark.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bird
                LeftSpark.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bird
                LeftSpark.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
                LeftSpark.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                leftSparkNode.addChild(LeftSpark)


                addChild(leftSparkNode)

            }
```

But like this sometimes they overlap each other because the generated `CGPoint` is too close to the previous one.

I am trying to add some amount of triangles to the wall and those triangles are rotated by 90°

To describe in image what I want to achieve:

[image]

And I want to avoid thing like this:

[image]

Comment: What you should really be doing, is making sure the new random point +- whatever threshold you want, is not already part of your leftPositions array.

Comment: What do you mean different by one?  What is the height of the textures?  I'll work up an answer in a few minutes. I deleted my first answer because I realized it was wrong.

Comment: Ok, i've posted a new answer.  Why are you nesting your SKSpriteNode in an SKNode?

Comment: Personally, I would generate a temporary pool of allowable y values into an array, and then just remove them as I go.  If I have time later on I may write code to show how it is done, but it would eliminate the chance of an infinite loop to happen. (In the accepted answer, let's say we randomly choose the same Y value [very tiny chance it happens but still 'possible',] we end up in an infinite loop, which is an undesired effect)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes I am aware of the loop and that it could happen but since I am that new to SpriteKit, I do not know my "tools". It would be awesome to see your solution with some explanation.

Comment: The basic idea is you make an array of y values, then you pick a random slot in this array. Now when you pick your random number y, you remove it from the array (as well as all of the other y values in the sprite height).  Now when you pull from the array a second time, it is impossible to pull one that overlaps, so all you would need to do is validate if there is enough y units available. if there isnt, go up the list until there is enough available, and if there is never enough available, then remove the y from the list and pull again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to this is not the best, i would suggest only storing the Y values in your position array and check against those values to make sure your nodes will not overlap.  The following will insure no two sparks are within 100 points of each other.  You may want to change that value depending on your node's actual height or use case.

Now, obviously if you end up adding too many sparks within an 800 point range, this just will not work and cause an endless loop.

```
var leftPositions = [Int]()
var yWouldOverlap = false
for _ in 0..<randRange(lower: 1, upper: 5){
  //Moved the random number generator to a function
  var newY = Int(randY())
  //Start a loop based on the yWouldOverlap Bool
  repeat{
    yWouldOverlap = false
    //Nested loop to range from +- 100 from the randomly generated Y
    for p in newY - 100...newY + 100{
      //If array already contains one of those values
      if leftPosition.contains(p){
        //Set the loop Bool to true, get a new random value, and break the nested for.
        yWouldOverlap = true
        newY = Int(randY())
        break
      }
    }
  }while(yWouldOverlap)
  //If we're here, the array does not contain the new value +- 100, so add it and move on.
  leftPositions.append(newY)
}

func randY() -> CGFloat{
   return Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: leftSparkMinimumY, secondNumber: leftSparkMaximumY)
}
```

And here is a different version of your following code.

```
for (index,y) in leftPositions.enumerated() {

  let leftSparkNode = SKNode()
  leftSparkNode.position = CGPoint(x:-295,y:CGFloat(y))
  leftSparkNode.name = "LeftSparks\(index)" //All node names should be unique

  let leftSparkTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "LeftSpark")
  LeftSpark = SKSpriteNode(texture: leftSparkTexture)

  LeftSpark.name = "LeftSparks"
  LeftSpark.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: leftSparkTexture, size: LeftSpark.size)
  LeftSpark.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.LeftSpark
  LeftSpark.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bird
  LeftSpark.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Bird
  LeftSpark.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
  LeftSpark.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
  leftSparkNode.addChild(LeftSpark)


  addChild(leftSparkNode)

}
```

Comment: Oops! I just noticed the last line is using a new random value instead of `newY`.  See my edit.  `leftPositions.append(randY())`, needs to be `leftPositions.append(newY)`

Comment: Add `yWouldOverlap = false` right after the `repeat` line.